Replicate `margins` from Stata and calculate the difference between two predicted means with 95%CI
I am hoping to replicate what the fabulous Chuck Huber produced here (margins). In this example, he was able to calculate the predicted birthweight for mothers who were smokers and who were non-smokers. The State code went something like this:
regress bwt age i.smoke
margins smoke

Where bwt = birthweight, age=age and i.smoke= smoker vs. non-smoker as a factor variable.
I have gotten this far
library(tidyverse)
library(margins)
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n,
           treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
           age=sample(18:80, n, replace=TRUE),
           sex = factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4))),
           smoke=factor(sample(c("Never", 'Former', 'Current'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.25, .6, .15))),
           score=runif(n, min=16, max=45))

mod <- lm(score~treat+age+sex+smoke, data=dat)
summary(margins(mod, variables = "treat"))

The output provides the average marginal effect (AME) for treat but only for a single level of this variable.
My questions are:

Is there a way for the output to show AME & 95%CI for treatTreat and treatControl (namely, the two levels of this factor)?
How can I compute a mean difference and 95%CI between these two AME for treatTreat and treatControl?

Many thanks,
Sandro

The margins package is no longer actively developed, and as of 2024-04-23 was not available on CRAN. This archiving may be temporary.
You can use the marginaleffects package instead (disclaimer: I am the author). The website includes over 30 chapters of tutorials and case studies, including an introductory Get Started page: https://marginaleffects.com
Before showing code, we need to agree on terminology. The margins smoke command in Stata computes “marginal predictions”, that is, average predictions by subgroups. This is not the same as the Average Marginal Effect that the margins package in R computes. The AME in this package is better called an “Average Slope”, and is defined as a partial derivative of the outcome equation with respect to the variable of interest.
You can compute all of these quantities easily with marginaleffects.  First, fit the model:
library(dplyr)
library(marginaleffects)
set.seed(42)
n <- 1000
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n,
           treat = factor(sample(c('Treat','Control'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.5, .5))),
           age=sample(18:80, n, replace=TRUE),
           sex = factor(sample(c('Male','Female'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.6, .4))),
           smoke=factor(sample(c("Never", 'Former', 'Current'), n, rep=TRUE, prob=c(.25, .6, .15))),
           score=runif(n, min=16, max=45))
mod <- lm(score~treat+age+sex+smoke, data=dat)

Now, compute average predictions for each subgroup of the treat variable. I show dplyr code so you understand exacly what is going on:
avg_predictions(mod, by = "treat")


       treat Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
     Treat       30.9       0.38 81.4   <0.001 Inf  30.2   31.7
     Control     30.9       0.36 86.0   <0.001 Inf  30.2   31.6

    Columns: treat, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
    Type:  response 

dat |> mutate(prediction = predict(mod, newdata = dat)) |>
    summarize(prediction = mean(prediction), .by = treat)

        treat prediction
    1   Treat   30.90587
    2 Control   30.92291

You can use the hypothesis argument to conduct a hypothesis test that compares the two quantities:
avg_predictions(mod, by = "treat", hypothesis = "sequential")

                Term Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
     Control - Treat    0.017      0.523 0.0326    0.974 0.0 -1.01   1.04

    Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
    Type:  response 

dat |> mutate(prediction = predict(mod, newdata = dat)) |>
    summarize(prediction = mean(prediction), .by = treat) |>
    summarize(diff = diff(prediction))

            diff
    1 0.01703766

Alternatively, you can compare average counterfactual predictions using the avg_comparisons() function:
avg_comparisons(mod, variables = "treat")

      Term        Contrast Estimate Std. Error       z Pr(>|z|)   S 2.5 % 97.5 %
     treat Treat - Control  -0.0108      0.523 -0.0207    0.983 0.0 -1.04   1.01

    Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
    Type:  response 

d0 <- mutate(dat, treat = "Control")
d1 <- mutate(dat, treat = "Treat")
mean(predict(mod, newdata = d1) - predict(mod, newdata = d0))

    [1] -0.01083374


Thank you @Vincent. It's always nice to hear directly from a package developer to explain their package functions.
